# Prevent UserForm from being visible when called from another macro in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am running a macro from one workbook (ie. wb1.xlsm) that copies a template workbook into another location and renames it (ie. wb2.xlsm).  It then uses Application.Run to run an AutoSetup() Sub located in wb2.  This creates the appropriate sheets based on the parameters its given.

My problem occurs during this process.  It is set up using existing functions which occur in a UserForm.

When I run the macro I do not want to see anything pop up, yet even with Application.Events and Application.Visible set to False The UserForm that performs the setup calculation still pops up and is visible.

Any suggestions?

Code below:

```
'AutoSetup Module
Public Sub AutoSetup(Project As String, Program As String, TestName As String, _
                     TestType As String, TaskNumber As String, Token As String)
    Dim TokenArr() As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set IntSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Integrations")
    Set DctSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Duct")
    IntSht.Range("B4").value = Program
    IntSht.Range("B5").value = TestName
    IntSht.Range("E4").value = Project
    IntSht.Range("E5").value = TaskNumber
    Call WorkbookSetup
    MenuForm.TestSetBox.value = TestType
    TokenArr = Split(Base64DecodeString(Token), ",")
    EPFLogin.TextBox1.value = TokenArr(0)
    EPFLogin.TextBox2.value = TokenArr(1)
    MenuForm.LoadSheets (True)
    DctSht.Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is there a userform ? Does it allow for some change in the calculation ? Can you post your code for AutoSetup(), so we can see what's happening ?

Comment: Do you have the rights (technically and in your organization) to update the template?

Comment: The UserForm (MenuForm) is used for Manual Setup.  Essentially I'm automating the process of the manual setup by sending the parameters a user would enter and then simulating the click event.

Comment: That I understood, and I assume you have to preserve the functionality of the original application to allow manual setup occasionaly, but __are you allowed__ to change the code?

Comment: Yes, I have the rights.

Comment: The LoadSheets Sub is located in the MenuForm Form... I'm wondering if the actual form has to be opened and visible to call said function.  I would assume no, but its VBA so....

Comment: I have actually already changed the code a bit.  MenuForm.LoadSheets was originally 
    Private Sub Okbtn_Click()
        'Code...
    End Sub
I changed that to 
    Public Sub LoadSheets(isAuto As Boolean)
        if isAuto = True Then
            'also do Automatic Setup routines
        End if
        'Code...
    End Sub
    Private Sub Okbtn_Click()
        Call LoadSheets(False)
    End Sub

Comment: menuform.hide , before menuform.loadsheets true. I guess something in menuform is updating a control values wich gives it focus.

Answer (score 1):

Within `wb2.xlsm`, move the calculations to a separate `Sub`routine in a separate module. Call this Subroutine from 'AutoSetup' after showing the `UserForm`.

Then from `wb1.xlsm`, call the new subroutine.

Comment: I want to avoid showing the UserForm at all during AutoSetup.  So your suggestion would be to perform all subroutines from a module instead of a form.

This is kind of what I assumed, but i was hoping that wasn't the case.

Comment: @StevenGood The suggestion is to move the part of the code that is doing the calculations out of the UserForm to a spot that is more sensible.  Then the UserForm (when it is displayed) can call those calculations (passing any parameters necessary), and your macro (**without** having to display the UserForm) can also call those calculations (passing any parameters necessary).  It is usually best if a form's code only includes the code related to the form itself.